# Create a List from Future results in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, future

I would like to create a list of results from several "asks" to a series of Akka actors.  So essentially I have a list of futures, and I would like to fill a list with those results, and then perform the next operation when all futures have returned.

Example:
The type of objects I expect to create the finished list with

```
case class Foo(id:Int, message:String)
```

The list of futures comes from:

```
val futures =
        context.children.map {
          child => {
            (child ? ("foo"))(5 seconds)
          }
        }
```

What do I do with `futures` to create a list of Foos?

```
val result = Await.result(futures.map(??????), 1 second).asInstanceOf[Foo]
```

Comment: I would avoid blocking on the aggregate `Future` (however you get it, via `Future.traverse` or `Future.sequence`) if possible.  Once you get the aggregate future, use a non-blocking callbacks (`onComplete`, `onSuccess`, `onFailure`) or one of the monadic methods like `map` or `flatMap` or even `foreach`.  Using `Await` will slow your system down and should be avoided is possible.

Comment: Also… "Tell, don't ask!" As with `Await`, there *are* circumstances in which it's necessary to `ask`, but it really is best to adhere to that Akka slogan as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Await.result` and `Future.traverse` to accomplish this.

```
-- create one big Future containing all the responses
val future = Future.traverse(context.children) { c => (c ? "foo")(5 seconds) }

-- now wait for it to return
val result = Await.result(future, 1 second)
```

`Future.traverse` is key here. Slightly simplifying, it takes `Traversable[A]` as it's first argument and a function `A => Future[B]` as it's second, then returns one big `Future[Traversable[B]]` which will complete once all the individual `Future`s complete and contain all the `B` results of the function.

Note that if **any** of the `Future`s fail, the combined `Future` will fail as well, which may or may not be what you want.

Also, it's usually recommended not to use `Await` as it introduces a sequential bottleneck in your asynchronous `Actors`, instead use `pipeTo` (or `onComplete` etc...) to send the result of the `Future` as a message to your `Actor` and then handle it accordingly.

Comment: Great answer (thank you), I can't quite get the big Future code to compile:  here's the compiler error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$qmark("foo")).  Would this work instead: val future = Future.traverse(context.children) (x => { (x ? "reportStatus")(5 seconds) })?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't have a scala compiler on hand. Yes, that should work

Comment: @binarygiant: Did this answer resolve your question?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Marked as the answer, and much appreciated.